# Dúvida sobre imagens no Android

Tags: android, imagem, diretório, organização-de-projeto, drawable

as imagens devem ficar na pasta drawable ou mipmap no meu projeto Android?

Eu venho utilizando a pasta mipmap. Existe alguma diferença na utilização dessas pastas em um projeto Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com um [blogpost do Google:](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density.

Ou seja, É uma boa prática utilizar a pasta mipmap exclusivamente para se colocar os ícones que serão utilizados na aplicação.
Qualquer outro asset de imagem deve ser colocado na pasta drawable.